# Forward a method without a signature

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm trying to write a forwarding library for libEGL.dll so I can catch calls being passed through it for debug.

The problem is the library is missing 2 methods `NvEglGetStdProcAddress` and `NvEglRegClientApi`.

This is a C library built for Arm7 (WinCE). The header file I have for libEGL doesn't include these 2 methods so I have no idea what the signature is in order to forward the calls.

Is there any way of forwarding the calls without knowing the signature?
Could I disassemble the dll and look for the parameters being popped from the stack?

DumpBin shows these at RVA 0x217C and Ox1E5C, /ALL /DISASM shows the .text section starting at 0x11000. How do I translate between these two offsets?

I'm guessing this wouldn't work, Would it just leave the parameters on the stack and then mangle them slightly with the local variable? What would happen to the return value (if there is one?)

```
typedef void (*NvEglGetStdProcAddressFunc) (void);
void NvEglGetStdProcAddress()
{
    NvEglGetStdProcAddressFunc ptr = (NvEglGetStdProcAddressFunc)GetProcAddress(hInst, _T("NvEglGetStdProcAddress"));
    ptr();
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about calling conventions on ARM, but in theory if you don't declare any local variables in your proxy function, and make it a "naked" function (one without any prologue or epilogue,) it would be possible to just "jump" (instead of call) to the real function address and be done with it. This makes adding debugging code a little harder (the part about no local variables) but it's nothing that can't be done.

Comment: @yzt Actually for these two I don't need any debug, just to pass the call straight through

Comment: OK, so you're probably all set (note that I don't know whether this actually works or not!) Anyways, if you are using MSVC, you can tag your function with [`__declspec(naked)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5w10wxs.aspx) to make it not push or pop stuff on and off the stack.

Comment: @yzt so how would I jump instead of call?

Comment: I don't understand. If the library doesn't have those functions, then how does anyone call them? If nobody can call them, then there are no existing calls that you'd need to forward. So what's the problem? What compiler, linker, or runtime error prompted you to ask this question?

Comment: @RobKennedy The library has the functions, The header file doesn't.

Comment: Then I ask again: How does anyone call them?

Comment: @RobKennedy Presumably there's another header file which I guess NVidia didn't publish. They are linked to by libKD.dll

Comment: @JamesBarrass: You use inline assembly (or actual assembly.) Unfortunately, I don't know anything about ARM ISA, so I can't give you working code or even a snippet for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply [forward export calls.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/02/04/7439592.aspx)

So my debug libEGL.dll `.def` file now has two extra lines at the top of it

```
; libEGL.def
EXPORTS
  NvEglGetStdProcAddress = libEGLOld.NvEglGetStdProcAddress 
  NvEglRegClientApi = libEGLOld.NvEglRegClientApi
  eglBindAPI
  eglBindTexImage
  ...
```

A colleague of mine tested this and verified it works, although it also **requires the ordinal to be specified**